# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS while using an NGINX reverse proxy?

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, https

I am trying to use NGINX on AWS for a reverse proxy to run a Node server. If I go to https://example.com/ , my connection is secure and everything is fine. But, when I go to http://example.com/ , no reroute occurs, and my connection is not secure. I am also using pm2 to run the Node server in the background.

I have tried the default server block reroutes that come up when I google the issue, but nothing has worked so far. My guess is that Node is handling requests on port 80, since my website comes up the way it did before I had my site fully set up. But I have no clue how to fix that.

Here are my server blocks in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
server {
   # if ($host = www.example.com) {
   #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   # } # managed by Certbot

    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  _;
    return       301 https://$host$request_uri; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com; # managed by Certbot
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on default_server; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl default_server; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # mana$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # ma$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Would appreciate any suggestions, as this is for a portfolio website and most places won't link directly to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has had this issue, I managed to fix the problem. After trying everything under the sun, I remembered that I messed with my iptables when following an online guide to remove the port number from the address. I fixed my issue by wiping my iptables config, and since I was using a proxy I didn't need to reroute the port.